# I used a ferment for the drug, but get an error

Tags: layout, attributes, android-resources, file-not-found, aapt2

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
F:\Android\tamrin android\PartnerPsychologist\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:error: attribute 'com.rahpars.partnerpsychologist:Layout' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.rahpars.partnerpsychologist:Layout' not found.
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking. The title contains details that need a lot more context, and there's no description or code here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you did a typo or a misinformed decision. There's no such layout as plain "Layout", which you are trying to use in your `activity_main.xml` file. Instead, you should use layouts like:

- LinearLayout
- GridLayout
- ContraintLayout
- TableLayout
- RelativeLayout

It all depends on your use-case. You can find more information about layouts in the [Developer's Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout).